# How do I change font color of all items on a QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm using the latest version of **Qt Designer** to make a PyQt app. I can't find a way to change the font color of the items in the dropdown. As you can see from the image bellow the text is not easy to see.

[image: Qt Designer preview of QComboBox]

This is my style sheet (QComboBox:items is not working)

[image: Qt Designer style sheet properties]

Is it possible to change the color of the items in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QComboBox is kind of like a QLineEdit(Active Selection), QPushButton(Down Arrow) and a QListView(Drop Down List) all together to make the QComboBox.

Within the css for the QComboBox you can call out these other PyQt objects and style them.

```
QComboBox{
    color: rgb(110,209,255);
}

QComboBox:items{
    color: rgb(110,209,255);
}

QListView{
    color: rgb(110,209,255);;
}
```

Try adding the QListView css when you're setting the style sheet of the QComboBox and that should fix your issue.

[image: QTDesignerScreenShot]

Comment: Some notes: 1. while, by default, the popup *is* a QListView, that can be overridden with `setView()` using *any* subclass of QAbstractItemView; 2. if that stylesheet is set for a parent (or the application) it would override *any* QListView subclass, so a proper *descendant selector* should be used instead; 3. `items` is not a recognized sub-control (and, while a single colon is normally also accepted, sub-controls should have two). Considering the above, the correct stylesheet should be: `QComboBox{ color: rgb(110, 209, 255); }` `QComboBox QAbstractItemView { color: rgb(110, 209, 255); }`

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you to [edit] your answer in order to reflect what said above, so that people won't need to read the comments to understand those important aspects.

Comment: I found a bug. When I change the font in the property editor, the stylesheet stops working 

Comment: @BrunoFerreira that seems unlikely, unless you're using some other stylesheet properties or a different and conflicting stylesheet in a parent.